# vue.js 2 @click on div not respond(without methods)

Tags: vuejs2

I try change color of div by clicked on him, but the event not responded,
what I'm doing wrong?
here is my code

**HTML**:

```
<div class="demo" @click="attachRed != attachRed" :class="{ red: attachRed }"></div>
```

**script**:
'

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      attachRed: false
}}
```

'
**style**:

```
.demo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is

`@click="attachRed = !attachRed`

Not

`@click="attachRed != attachRed`

The `!=` symbol is a test operator, and is read as "not equal," so what you have is "attachRed is not equal to attachRed." You should use the assignment operator of just `=` and negate the right-hand value. It should read "attachRed is assigned to NOT (!) attachRed."

Comment: thanks! I just solved the stupid mistake:)

Comment: Don't worry it happens to everybody. I am confused my answer helped you?